# Angular 10 Call backend API with query param use_cache:false only once at load or refresh. at other time use_cache:true

Tags: angular, angular-material, ngrx, angular-material2, ngrx-effects

I have an backend python api which uses flag `use_cache` which caches data pulled from datastore.

In Angular 10 Frontend, we call this api with `use_cache: false` for now but takes 7-10secs to load without caching,

how do i make sure to `use_cache: false` at angular application load or reload. but once application is loaded api is always called with `use_cache: true` ??

Comment: What does refresh time mean? Page reload or some specific "refresh time", such as every X minutes?

Comment: @Bojan Kogoj updated. only at application load for first time or browser window reload

Comment: Would this not just be a parameter in the function that calls your api? You can use `ngOnInit` in your top level component to make the call on load / refresh